# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported - File Upload

Tags: post

**HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported**

**type** Status report

**message** Request method 'POST' not supported

**description** The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

**Apache Tomcat/7.0.42** [apk indir](http://korsandroid.com) Homepage for click.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $filedir = ""; 
    $maxfile = '2000000';

    $userfile_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $abod = $filedir.$userfile_name;
        @move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $abod);

echo"<center><b>Done ==> $userfile_name</b></center>";
}
}
else{
echo'
<form method="GET" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="image"><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></form>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [http-get-with-request-body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) and also [this table](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) comparing GET and POST.

The GET method does not carry a meaningful body and so does not support multipart nor file upload.  Most likey this is being sent by the browser as a POST request.

Make sure the `web-resource-collection` tag in your servlet's `web.xml` file contains `<http-method>POST</http-method>` so Tomcat will allow your POST request.